# Sort Scala, first by value and then by key

Tags: scala, sorting

I have an array of pairs:

```
Array(("hello",200.00),("name",100.00),("a",200.00),("say",150.67))
```

I want it sorted as:

```
Array(("a",200.00),("hello",200.00),("say",150.67),("name",100.00))
```

Sorted in descending by value first, then ascending by key

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: I'm working on a spark cluster. So i used sortBy command, but this sorts by only key OR value

Comment: Well... then why are you using Array. If you want any benefits of Spark use RDD. Show us the code, then may be we can help.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks. I was using RDDs. I used filter and then collect to get a portion of the data that I wanted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple as

```
array sortBy {case (k,v) => (-v,k)}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using sortWith:

```
val a = Array(("hello",200.00),("name",100.00),("a",200.00),("say",150.67))
val sorted = a.sortWith((a, b) => a._2 > b._2 || (a._2 == b._2 && a._1 < b._1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group by Value -> Sort it -> map each of the grouped to sorted by key Seq -> reverse all Seq

```
val groupdByValue = a.groupBy { case (k, v) => v }.toSeq
val groupsSortedByValue = groupdByValue.sortBy { case (value, group) => value }
val sortedByValueThenKey = groupsSortedByValue.flatMap { case (k, v) => v.sortBy { case (k, v) => v } }.reverse
```

sortedByValueThenKey: Seq[(String, Double)] = ArrayBuffer((a,200.0), (hello,200.0), (say,150.67), (name,100.0))